# error while loading shared libraries in sudo

Tags: c++, unix, linker

I read documentation on https://github.com/openyou/libomron/blob/master/README.asciidoc

Exec:

```
cd /
sudo find . | grep libomron.so.0.9.0
```

result:

```
./home/splincode/Develop/omron/c++_modules/libomron/omron-build/lib/
```

Okey, I add library in global path

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/splincode/Develop/omron/c++_modules/libomron/omron-build/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then it's work:

```
 cd ~/Develop/omron/usr/local/bin/
 ./omron_790IT_test
```

But, not access in hardware, result

```
 Found 1 omron 790ITs
 Cannot open omron 790IT!
```

as a result, I began to run as administrator, but he does not see the library, what to do?

```
sudo ./omron_790IT_test
```

Result:

```
 ./omron_790IT_test: error while loading shared libraries: libomron.so.0.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: As root you have not exported the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, hence the error. `omron_790IT_test` doesn't have that problem, it cannot access  the device, nothing to do with shared libraries.

Comment: but with sudo unix not found library

Comment: `sudo` runs your code as `root`. You modified the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for your user, not for root.

Comment: how modified for root, please?

Comment: because, me run "sudo su" then "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/splincode/Develop/omron/c++_modules/libomron/omron-build/lib/"

Comment: try `sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/splincode/Develop/omr‌​on/c++_modules/libom‌​ron/omron-build/lib/‌​ ./omron_790IT_test`

Comment: incorrect, write usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `./omron_790IT_test: error while loading shared libraries`

This is happening because by default `sudo` does *not* propagate environment variables; doing so presents a security risk.

You can deal with this in one of three ways:

1. Link your program in a way that *doesn't* require `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be set (this is *the best* approach).

   In your case, the link command should look something like this:

   `gcc -o omron_790IT_test  ... \
     -Wl,-rpath=/home/splincode/Develop/omron/c++_modules/libomron/omron-build/lib`
2. Explicitly set the wanted environment variable inside the sudo process:

   `sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... ./omron_790IT_test`
3. Ask `sudo` to propagate all environment variables into the root process:

   `sudo -E ./omron_790IT_test`

   `sudo --preserve-env ./omron_790IT_test`